# Hex String to BYTE c++

Tags: c++, string, hex, byte

I am trying to convert a hex string in the form of

```
std::string mystring = "00A4040C06FF5142534014";
```

to a BYTE in a form of:

```
BYTE cmd2[] = {0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x0C, 0x06, 0xFF, 0x51, 0x42, 0x53, 0x40, 0x14};
```

I tried using the following function:

```
std::vector<char> HexToBytes(const std::string& hex)
{
    std::vector<char> bytes;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i += 2) {
        std::string byteString = hex.substr(i, 2);
        char byte = (char) strtol(byteString.c_str(), NULL, 16);
        bytes.push_back(byte);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

But this didnt give me the right conversion. Maybe someone could help me out?

Comment: What result do you get? Have you tried to step through the code statement by statement in a debugger to see what happens?

Comment: *"this didnt give me the right conversion"* - what *did* it give you, and how did you verify that? I suspect your use of standard `char` as opposed to `unsigned char` as your octet target may be giving you something you weren't expecting.

Comment: What is the 'right conversion??'

Comment: The code works as is, no problem so far.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. When I insert bytes into another function where i normally insert cmd2 I get the error:
cannot convert 'std::vector<char>' to 'LPCBYTE {aka const unsigned char*}'
The function is called SCardTransmit from winscard.h

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Maybe it helps if you change `char` to `unsigned char`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/7MuGG0NhnrLM6TFo

Comment: That error has nothing to do with this conversion. it has to do with trying to pass a `std::vector<char>` *argument* to a function expecting a `LPCBYTE` parameter.

Comment: Thank you @WhozCraig. Do you know how to convert it to a LPCBYTE?

Answer (score 2):

There's no implicit conversion from `std::vector<char>` to `const unsigned char*`.

```cpp
std::vector<BYTE> HexToBytes(const std::string& hex)
{
    std::vector<BYTE> bytes;
...
```

```cpp
auto cmd = HexToBytes(mystring);
rv = SCardTransmit(hCard, &pioSendPci, &cmd[0], cmd.size(), NULL, pbRecvBuffer, &dwRecvLength);
```